# how can I migrate the database dump of MongoDB into PostgreSQL?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql, rails-postgresql

I replicate the application using the database as postgresql but later on I came to know that application was using mongodb and I got the dump of the app in json format which was of mongodb.

So any help regarding to migrate the mongo db dump into postgresql will be so appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: MongoDB is a schema-less database where PostgreSQL is an RDBMS. So, Migration is largely depending on data model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can migrate MongoDB into PostgreSQL using MoSQL.

Follow the [github](https://github.com/stripe/mosql) page of MoSQL. It contains the information, how you can do the migration.

Follow the this [blog](https://stripe.com/blog/announcing-mosql) post for more information

Comment: I go through with above link but could not find out any relevant info which can directly convert MongoDB into PostgreSQL.

Comment: I did not find any solution that can convert MongoDB into PostgreSQL directly. But, the given solution is a way to convert MongoDB into PostgreSQL.